# call_user_func_array does not execute __callStatic magic method

Tags: php, magic-methods

I have these two classes:

```
class Service {
    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        // ... opt-out code
        $result = call_user_func_array([CacheService::class, $name], $arguments);
        // ... opt-out code
    }
}
```

And this

```
class CacheService
{
    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        // ... opt-out code
        if (self::getCacheInstance()->has('some_cache_key')) {
            return call_user_func_array(['self', $name], $arguments);
        }
        // ... opt-out code
    }

    public static function getItems()
    {
        //... do operations
    }
}
```

When I call `Service::getItems();` from the controller, it executes `__callStatic` in `Service` class, but when `Service` class attempts to call `getItems()` from CacheService, it does not execute `__callStatic` in `CacheService` class.
What is the problem exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__callStatic` is only executed when there is no static method with the calling method name

Your `Service` class does not contain a `getItems()` method so `__callStatic` gets executed.

Your `CacheService` does contain it so `getItems` gets executed instead

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic

Example:

```php
<?php

class A {
    public static function __callStatic() {
        echo "A::__callStatic";
    }
}

class B {
    public static function __callStatic() {
        echo "B::__callStatic";
    }

    public static function getItems() {
        echo "B::getItems";
    }
}

A::getItems(); // A::__callStatic
B::getItems(); // B::getItems()
B::anotherFunction(); // B::__callStatic
```